# Calling shell script from PHP is not working as expected

Tags: php, shell

I am trying to open remote machine browser from my machine. I have setup password less connection ( considering the fact that both systems are in same n/w and are trusted).

I am able to run below script to launch browser, which takes 3 arguments

a). userName
b). ip address of remote machine
c). url to open in firefox

If i run this script in my bash shell, i am able to open the browser without any issues. But if i call this inside PHP, i am not able to launch the browser on remote machine...it shows all debug prints but fails open browser. Any pointers are greatly helpful.
 Below is my shell script to open browser on remote machine.

```
#!/bin/bash
if test $# != 3;
then
     echo "
         $0
         This command line script is used to launch, browser remotely. You need to pass 3 arguments to this script.
         YOU NEED TO PASS 3 ARGUMEMTS TO THIS SCRIPT,
         For example , \$> sh $0 \"<userNameofRemoteSystem>\"  \"<remoteSystemIP>\"  \"<webPageAddress>\"

         \$> sh $0 \"Uname\" \"172.17.64.94\"  \"mail.google.com\" \n";
         exit 1
fi

echo "<br><br>\nRECEIVED PARAMETERS,\n\tuserName\t-> |$1|\n\tipAddress\t-> |$2|\n\twebURL\t\t-> |$3|\n\n<br>";
echo "<br>Checking if Connection to |$2| WITH USERNAME |$1| is password less???<br><br>";
sleep 2

echo "<br>grep -wc $1 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys<br>";
count=`grep -wc $1 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`;
echo "<br>got process count=|$count|<br>"

sleep 2

if [ "$count" != 1 ];
then
    echo "
       Looks like password less connection to |$2| is not configured with this server for username |$1|..
       Please congfigure the same and run this script again...\n";
fi

echo "SUCCESSFULLY CONNECTED, LAUNCHING BROWSER ON |$2| WITH |$3|\n";
ssh $1@$2 "nohup sh openBrowser.sh $3" &
PID=$$;
echo "PID IS |$PID|\n";
sleep 2;
echo "<br>PROCESS OUTPUT LOOKS LIKE THIS";
ps aux | grep $PID | grep -v grep
echo "<br>";
echo "after sleep";
kill -9 $PID && echo "after kill pid=$PID, passed ssh $1@$2 \"nohup sh openBrowser.sh $3\" &";
```

Below is the php script i am using to call the shell script.

```
<?php
    $c_url=$_POST['url'];
    $c_name=$_POST['uname'];
    $c_ip=$_POST['ipaddress'];

    $output = system("/bin/sh /home/user/launchBrowser_remote.sh $uName $ipADDR $c_url");
    echo "$output";
?>
```

Looks like i am getting wrong PID inside shell script and its killing the caller script rather than launching the ssh to remote ..... BTW i have tried both `exec` and `shell_exec` but no luck.

Any pointer are greatly helpful
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the user that is running the php file (web server user if being called in that context) is set up for password-less authentication as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, web server didn't had the password less connection, this fixed the issue. Thanks again.